# If language show

Tags: php, themes

my site has 3 languages ​​in my node--service.tpl.php get the following

```
 <?php
        if ($language = 'es'):
        ?> 
    <div class="more"><a href="<?php print $base_url . $node_url ?>">Leer más</a></div>
     <?php elseif ($language = 'en'): ?>
      <div class="more"><a href="<?php print $base_url . $node_url ?>">Read more</a></div>
      <?php else: ?>
      <div class="more"><a href="<?php print $base_url . $node_url ?>">Leere más</a></div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

however, only shows me this language es even a page en. Only shows me the first div.

Comment: `if ($language = 'es'):` assigns the value 'es' to the variable `$language`. `if ($language == 'es'):` for logical comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
if ($language == 'es'):
```

You are using the wrong operator and your `$language` will always be 'es' because you are asigning a value not comparing

Comment: technically, it's an assignment and implicitly comparing the assigned value for its truthiness. Unless you were doing `$language = ''` or something similar, it'll evaluate to true.